# trying to remove "sep1" item from the jquery-contextmenu menu dynamically. How do i approach it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

I am using [jquery-contextmenu](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/) for my project. I have following menu created where i have several separators (sep1,sep2...etc) that i need to hide dynamically. how do I approach it? The problem is when I hide some items dynamically the separators are still visible.

```
$.contextMenu({
    selector: '#ItemSelector',
    callback: function (key, options) {
        var m = "clicked: " + key;
        window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);

        //handle event once right click is pressed on any option.

    },
    events: {
        show: function (options) {
           //some code
        }
    },
    items: {
        "menu_context_selection": {
            name: "Start/Stop Selection",
            icon: "fa-check-square-o",
            visible: function (key, opt) {
                return !true;
            }
        },
        "menu_context_open": {
            name: "Open",
            icon: "fa-folder-open-o",
            visible: function (key, opt) {
                return true;
            }

        },
        "sep1": "---------",
        "menu_context_rename": {
            name: "Rename",
            icon: "fa-keyboard-o",
            visible: function (key, opt) {
                return !true;
            }
        },
        "menu_context_delete": {
            name: "Delete",
            icon: "fa-recycle",
            visible: function (key, opt) {
                return !true;
            }
        },
        "sep2": "---------",
        "menu_context_newfolder": {
            name: "New Folder",
            icon: "fa-folder-o",
            visible: function (key, opt) {
                return !true;
            }
        },
        "sep3": "---------",
        "menu_context_copy": {
            name: "Copy",
            icon: "fa-files-o",
            visible: function (key, opt) {
                return !true;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: have you tried attaching the visible function used on the item to the separator?

Comment: either that or try using items: function() { return list of items you want them to see}

Comment: which one do you want to hide? above or below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just return a object with the visible property set to false

```
"sep1": true ? "---------" : {visible: false}
```